# Composer lib copy a file to parent project once installed

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a composer library developed and I want, once have been installed it copies a file to the parent project.
I have seen the composer's Events [(Scripts)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) but that doesn't work for me because as is described in composer documentation:

"Note: Only scripts defined in the root package's composer.json are executed. If a dependency of the root package specifies its own scripts, Composer does not execute those additional scripts."([see](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-))

know someone any trick or hack to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to security issues.

If anyone could reach your file system just on `composer update`, he or she could add a file, but also **remove anything**.

That's why use has to add those scripts manually to their root's `composer.json`.

---

Common practise is to describe this in `README.md` as one of install steps.

What exactly do you need to add?